# Is it legal to have the same software name?

Tags: branding

I am thinking of a name to give to a **distinct format of file**. It is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or XML file that store the location of things found on the internet, much like an address (as the format) that point a specific location.

Something like (clip, clippings, clipp, clippr, clipps, clips, clipr, clippers).

This name will be given to the file type and the app/software that reads it.

**Example:** Open `<filename>.clipp.json` with android app **Clipp**.

> Note: **Clipp** has been used to name an app that helps you book a restaurant. See: clipp.co

Some of these names have been taken by one brand (like clipp, clippr and clipps). Some are taken by multiple brands sharing the same name (like clips and clipper). Some are just general names used by many other apps and brands as well (like clip and clippings).

As much as copyright and trademarks are concerned (as discussed in: [Brand piracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_piracy)).

1. Is it legal to have same software/app name?
2. .. with different logo?
3. .. have different target market (while one app is a browser, the other is a note manager)
4. .. with a brand that uses common verb or noun like (tyre,clipper,move,bags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, trademark laws are sort of case by case.
The general rule is, if there is a chance people will be confused about which product they're getting, you're infringing on their trademark.
The legal guideline takes several things into consideration, including the things you listed above:

A trademark claim is stronger the closer the products are.
(Frank's burgers Frank's detergent would probably be okay)

A trademark is weaker if it has a very common verb/noun, and stronger if it is a special word phrase.
(So Google groceries would probably infringe, even though they're different sectors)

The trademark is stronger if the company has registered it (and maintained it).

The logo could be used to show that you were trying to confuse consumers if they look similar, which is the point of trademarks: they show who made a product.

As long as there's little chance of people thinking your product was made from someone else, you generally don't get into trouble.

Comment: I once published an app with a similar name to another. Google does **not** follow these rules. They do not wait for a court order. They simply remove the app and penalize the developer account that uploaded it.